# Cancel the effect of inertia in the movement of the maps in OSMDROID

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I need to cancel the effect of inertia in the movement of the maps in `OSMDROID`. I tried to modify the code but I don't get anything. Any idea how?

Comment: Extend MapView and override dispatchTouchEvent: 

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        getController().stopAnimation(false);
        
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

Comment: I try with true and with false, no results in both cases

Comment: I also try to use de Controller.stopAnimation in other cases but never get result.

Answer (score 3):

Check onFling method in MapView.MapViewGestureDetectorListener class and change velocityX, velocityX to your implementation, something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2,
        float velocityX,float velocityY) {
    velocityX=(float) Math.sqrt(velocityX);
    velocityY=(float) Math.sqrt(velocityY);
    if (MapView.this.getOverlayManager()
        .onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY, MapView.this)) {
            return true;
        }...
```