# OSMDroid 4.0 cancel map inertia

Tags: android, dictionary, animation, osmdroid

I am using OSMDroid 4.0 and i can't find a solution to cancel the map inertia because of issues with multi-touch zooming. I have viewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939351/cancel-the-effect-of-inertia-in-the-movement-of-the-maps-in-osmdroid) but `MapViewGestureDetectorListener` is `private` so it cannot be accessed.

I would like to not go thru all the trouble of editing and recompiling the map on every release that they do.

Is there any other possibility to cancel the animation?